# Validate two textboxes (C #)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10

I have two textboxes, which prompts the user to enter an integer in each of them. I already have the code all done (code to validate if the texboxes are not empty, if only integers are entered and if the number inserted in the 2nd texbox is greater than the number entered in the 1st texbox.
I leave here a simple example of my code (I already have all the code done):

```
private async void generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(min.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(max.Text))
    {
        // I already have the code done ...
        // error message
    }    
    else
    { 
        // I already have the code done ...
        // Here it does the operation with the two numbers entered
    }
}

private async void min_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(min.Text, "[^0-9]"))
    {
        // I already have the code done ...
        // error message
    }

}

private async void max_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(max.Text, "[^0-9]"))
    {
        // I already have the code done ...
        // error message
    }
}
```

I only have one question: Where do I put the code (I already have this code done) to verify that the number entered in the 2nd textbox is greater than the number entered in the 1st texbox? This is my question.

Update: I just want to know where I put the code:

```
if (maxValue < minValue) 
{ 
     // I already have the code done ... 
     // error message 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate all of this validation logic in a function the returns a bool

```
private bool IsValid ()
{
 if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(min.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(max.Text))
    {
       // return false any where the input is not valid
    }    

}
```

then use an if statment inside Your Button click Event Handler

```
if (IsValid())
{
   //Code To Check If Max is Bigger Than min
}
```

this Way You Can Easily Call The IsVaild Function To Check For Empty String 
You Can Also Encapsulate The Logic To Validate The Bigger Number in Another function if u gonna use it alot

Hope I Fully Understood You

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I could not figure it out. I continue with my doubt.
For example in my code (and this is in the example: generate_Click), I have a button and when the user clicks this button it will check if the two text boxes are not empty. If they are empty it presents an error message (1st if), if not, it does the operation that I intend (it is in the else)
In the min_TextChanged and max_TextChanged will check if the user entered integers. If you did not enter whole numbers you get an error message.

Comment: Cosnider using a masked Text box If You Want Numbers only

Comment: That's not my doubt.
I just want to know where I put the code:
`if (maxValue < minValue)
    {
        // I already have the code done ...
        // error message
}`

Comment: But I just now want to check if the number entered in the 2nd textbox is greater than the number entered in the 1st texbox. I have this done, I just do not know where to put this code.

Answer (score 0):

If your confusion is only where to put the verification code of the number entered in the 2nd textbox is greater than the number entered in the 1st textbox, you can simply check this after the button click. Here's the sample:

```
        private async void generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(min.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(max.Text))
            {
                await new MessageDialog("Text boxes cannot be empty").ShowAsync();
                return;
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(max.Text) < Convert.ToInt32(min.Text))
            {
                await new MessageDialog("1st one is bigger").ShowAsync();
                //you may do as you want, showing a message box is just a sample
            }
            else
            {
                await new MessageDialog("2nd one is bigger").ShowAsync();
                //you may do as you want, showing a message box is just a sample
            }
        }
```

And for your clarification onTextChanged events may be like this:

```
        private async void min_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(min.Text, "[^0-9]") )
            {
                await new MessageDialog("Enter numbers only.").ShowAsync();
                //you may do as you want, showing a message box is just a sample
            }

        }
        private async void max_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(max.Text, "[^0-9]"))
            {
                await new MessageDialog("Enter numbers only.").ShowAsync();
                //you may do as you want, showing a message box is just a sample
            }

        }
```

So here the summary is, if the textboxes are empty it will show a warning and return. And after the user finishes the input number and presses the button it will check which number is bigger. And a warning will also showed if users give input rather than numbers. Hope this may help you.